# Cruise Control and MSBuild. Building only one project in a solution

Tags: svn, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am using cruise control and MSBuild. I am pulling a solution from SVN, this errors on the remote machine for one of the projects. 
The failing project is not necessary for the deployment of my solution. 
How can I make cruise control and msbuild build just specifically the project I choose and its dependencies instead of the entire solution?

Answer (score 2):

If the csproj does any "By Project" references to other csproj's in the same solution, you cannot.  You have to build the entire .sln.

If it is "stand alone", then build it using the MyProject.csproj name, and not the MySolution.sln file name.

Comment: Just a note here - you can build any csproj file that has project references via msbuild directly using the /p:BuildProjectReferences=true flag regardless of Solution file inclusion.

Comment: Dang.  Learn something new each day.  Great tip Nick, thanks.

Comment: It's my pleasure - Cheers!  It's a quite useful feature in a codebase that's large and uses proj files for traversal rather than behemoth sln files.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a different build configuration in your SLN, that does not build that target. Look at your build configurations thru the Build->Configuration manager menu options